# Upload Data from text file to databse using SQL Loader

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, sql-loader

I've tried inserting 2 Million records in traditional way and using Hiberante Batch. But they take a lot of time. i heard that we can insert the same number of records using SQL loader in very less time.

So, this is my question: 
I have to insert 2 Million records using SQL Loader.

***File Structure:***

> [Header1]
>
> [Detail-for-header1]
>
> [Header2]
>
> [Detail-for-header2]
>
> .
>
> .

***File.txt***

**Header1 --- Department 1 -- USD (Us Dollar)**

[Data Under Header 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuFUy.png)

Similarly, Header2 May have CAD( Canadian Dollar as currency )

So, while inserting records of Header1 in the table.
As header1 has USD as currency code. I want to add a USD as currency code for every record under header1.

Like This

[Data Under Header1 after Inserting in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDhL7.png)

if i use conditional loop . i can do this

```
if(lineData.startsWith("HEADER")
{
currencyCode = lineData.substring(Start_Position_of_currency_code, End_Position_of_currency_code).trim();
isExistCc = currencyCode.equalsIgnoreCase("SGD");
if(isExistCc)
{
for Every Record Under Header1 - Write Currency Code as USD
}
```

But, Is there anyway using Conditional Loop in a .CTL File - SQL Loader.

Else, Is there any other alternative to insert currency code for every record while inserting million records.

Comment: show us your data

but it sounds like you need to move your header line data into the stream you want to insert, or in other words, each line should also have the currency code

Comment: Yeah, there are so many headers in a file , each header has a currency code. So if i have a for or while loop then i can iterate same currency code until it finds another header. So far i know i cant give for loop or while loop inside a .ctl  (control ) file . are there any alternatives

Comment: A file may contain 'n' number of headers,detail(dtl),tail(tlr) . 1st header has USD as currency so all records under that should be added with a new column called "currency code" with "USD" as their code . Similar all records under 2nd header should have a "SGD" as currency code  . 

[Visit the link for Sample Data](https://github.com/AsishKakumanu/File/blob/master/Random)

So is there a way to do that using sql loader .ctl else is there any other way



Thanks in advance :)